# Get body markup of an AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call:

```
callAjaxController: function(){
        var url = Routing.generate('ajax_price');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            cache: false,

            success: function (data, status) {
                // get the <body> markup to replace my actual body page
            }
        })
    },
```

In my Ajax response, I would like to get the `<body>` markup to replace my actual body page.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your request retrieves the content of the `body` tag you want to use you can set the `html()` of the current `body()` element with the new content, like this:

```
success: function (data, status) {
    $('body').html(data);
}
```

Alternatively, if the response includes the `<body>` tag and all content within it, use `replaceWith()`:

```
success: function (data, status) {
    $('body').replaceWith(data);
}
```

Also note that because you have destroyed all existing elements in the DOM you will need to use delegated event handlers, should you have any existing events that are handled in code.

Comment: What if the response is a full html page including <!doctype html> and <html> elements

Comment: In which case you'd be better off using `load()` and targeting the element you want to retrieve within the arguments you provide to the function. You should note that returning an entire HTML page to an AJAX request isn't good practice.

Comment: The ajax is returning a full html page but I just want the body part like it says in the question. I tried $(html).find("body") but that doesn't work for some reason